# Andengine gles2 - weird JPG look

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I want load backgound texture from JPG, scale it down to proper size. So I have 1920x1080 picture and I scale it to ~800x480.

```
BitmapTextureAtlas splashTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 1920, 1080, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        splashTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(splashTextureAtlas, this, "new/splash_bg1.JPG", 0, 0);
        splashTextureAtlas.load();

Sprite splash = new Sprite(0, 0, splashTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        splash.setScale(mainScaleX);
```

And effect is poor.

Orginal File

[image]

What I see on screen

[image]

I try with diffrent TextureOption but without any effect.
Could you suggest me what I'm doing wrong?

---

### UPDATE

Even when I keep aspect ratio quality is poor

[image]

Comment: This is not a weird problem , its called banding of colors and it happens to the gradient images, you can solve it by using the dither, and one of the advantage of dither is that you can use a small (100X100) with same gradient and u can scale them up to (1000X1000) and still have a neat looking gradient background and save space of texture space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, dither is disabled for performance reasons. For gradient textures that are experiencing really bad banding, try adding this to your sprite creation:

```
Sprite splash = new Sprite(0, 0, splashTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

    protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) {
        super.preDraw(pGlState, pCamera);
        pGlState.enableDither();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem may be in your scaling - at 1920x1080 you have an aspect ratio of 1.777 - but at 800x480, the aspect ratio is 1.667.

Try scaling the image to 800x450 or 853x480 to preserve the aspect ratio of 1.777 - if you truly need 800x480, then crop the image to those specs after you scale the size down.

Comment: I just update my question, I forgot mention about it :)